# Let user know when email verified

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

When the user wants to update the email, I'm using `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail` to verify before updating it.

```dart
await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.verifyBeforeUpdateEmail(
    email,
    ActionCodeSettings(
      androidInstallApp: true,
      androidPackageName: 'com.example',
      iOSBundleId: 'com.example',
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      url: 'https://example.page.link/emailVerify',
    ));
```

Can I let the user know if the email has been verified and updated? I've tried [dynamic_links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) but it does not pick up the email verification.

Comment: Have you tried firebase functions?

Comment: As @renaud-tarnec's answer mentions, there's no way to get/listen to user changes other than creating and deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `verifyBeforeUpdateEmail()` method sends a verification email to a new email address. So the user **needs to execute an action** in order to verify the email (click on the link provided in the email). So normally the user will know he/she has verified the new email.

If you want to add an extra mechanism to "let the user know if the email has been verified and updated" you could adopt one of the following approaches:

**#1 Implement a custom email action handler**

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler), "by default, user management emails link to the default action handler, which is a web page hosted at a URL in your project's Firebase Hosting domain. You can instead create and host a custom email action handler to do custom processing and to integrate the email action handler with your website".

This way, you could implement any business logic in parallel of the email verification, like sending a confirmation email or updating a flag, etc..

**#2 Use a Cloud Function**

There is no Authentication Cloud Functions trigger in response to the verification of an email, unfortunately. We can only trigger a Cloud Function upon the creation and deletion of Firebase user accounts. But you could implement a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) which checks if the email has been verified.

Comment: If I understand correctly and based on my research on documentation, I have to generate an [email action link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link). With this, if the user has the app installed I can handle the code in the app by calling `applyActionCode` as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/passing-state-in-email-actions#handling_email_actions_in_a_mobile_application).

Comment: Yes that’s it!!