# How can we save data to firestore after email verification in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save user data in firestore when the email is verified, which is the best practice I guess.

I already did everything but I don't know how to save my user to a user collection **when the email is verified.**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: did you try to detect in your code that the email is verified, and then write that information to Firebase?

Comment: YES, the problem is that I don't have a verification page, when the user clicks login or signup it sends an email immediately when the user clicks on the link how am I going to save user info according to this event?

Comment: There is no notification action to your Flutter code when the user clicks the email link, since that verification happens elsewhere (either in their email client or in a browser popped up from there). You could implement a server-side check like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827663/let-user-know-when-email-verified or a client-side check as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192651/, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068181, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63258198